# PUT request to another server with header is not working

Tags: php, curl, put, php-curl

I want to create a put request to another server including some data and header. But it it is not redirecting to the target url.

Here is what i wrote:

```
    $pay_time = '01-01-2020';
    $url = 'https://demo.sparktbd.com/api/response.php';
    $fields = array( 
            'payment_status' => '0', 
            'payment_datetime' => $pay_time, 
            ); 

    $fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("user: sohel", "pass: Sohel@123"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch); 
    var_dump($fields_string);
```

And i will get the following data at requested server:

```
{
    "payment_status": "0",
    "payment_datetime":"01-01-2020"
}
```

Please help me to find what i am missing

Answer (score 0):

Your question mentions PUT requests but in your code you set it as a POST request.

The line

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));`

should be updated to

`curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"PUT")`

in order for CURL to perform a PUT request.

Comment: Still it is staying in same page.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly, the PUT request is not being received at `https://demo.sparktbd.com/praava/api/response.php`?

Comment: No. Its not sending anything there.